# swift map view does not display circle overlay SOLVED

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, mapkit

The Correct Code is in the solution. The error below I refer to is occurring on the solution.

Hello I solved this my self but here is the code to display a circle ontop of a region in map kit. You just have to provide a state and city and it will place a circle ontop of that region. When I run this code everything works properly but I get this in the output

"Missing MeshRenderables for ground mesh layer for (6/6) of ground tiles. Tile debug info: (Key: 0.2.2.255 t:34 kt:0, Has mesh errors: 0, MeshInstance count: 1, PendingMaterial count: 1, Invisible MeshInstances count: 0 | Key: 1.0.2.255 t:34 kt:0, Has mesh errors: 0, MeshInstance count: 2, PendingMaterial count: 2, Invisible MeshInstances count: 0 |"

if anyone knows how to get ride of this id appreciate the help.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion
    let circleRadius: CLLocationDistance
    @Binding var regionToDisplay: MKCoordinateRegion?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView()
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        let circle = MKCircle(center: region.center, radius: circleRadius)
        view.addOverlay(circle)
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.black
        let greenColorWithOpacity = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        circleRenderer.fillColor = greenColorWithOpacity
        circleRenderer.lineWidth = 3.0
        return circleRenderer
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer because it *ruins* the question.

Comment: @vadian sorry, I put back the original (wrong) code into the question and posted the correct code as a solution. I still get a weird error on my solution. Maybe you know a fix. Thanks

Comment: At least create the overlay in `updateUIView`, not in `makeUIView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @State private var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.5202471, -122.6741949)
    let city: String
    let state: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator

        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        let address = "\(city), \(state)"
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
            if let placemark = placemarks?.first, let location = placemark.location {
                self.coordinate = location.coordinate
                mapView.setCenter(self.coordinate, animated: true)
                
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
                mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

                let regionRadius = 3500.0
                let circle = MKCircle(center: coordinate, radius: regionRadius)
                mapView.addOverlay(circle)
            }
        }
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
            if let circle = overlay as? MKCircle {
                let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(circle: circle)
                circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.black
                circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
                circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
                return circleRenderer
            }
            return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please add an explanation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).